# Rails Devise - Different redirect paths on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, routes, registration

I'm using devise for users but I have two types of users (customers and suppliers), and need different redirect routes based on which path they follow. EG: If a customer signs (`/signup`) up it will redirect them to their dashboard. If a supplier signs up(`/suppliers/registrations/user`), it needs to direct them to the next form where they start describing their business(`/suppliers/registrations/business`). How do you manage this?

**UPDATE**
I've update my devise registrations controller to include the following (I've excluded all of the commented out stuff)

**users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      if resource.supplier == true
        redirect_to supplier_business_path
      elsif resource.supplier == false
        redirect_to user_projects_path(current_user)
      end
    end
end
```

But it keeps taking me to the root regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after_sign_in_path_for should just return the path but not perform a redirect, try changing your method like this:

```
protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      if resource.supplier == true
         # also add specific url = '/suppliers/registrations/user'
        supplier_business_path
      elsif resource.supplier == false
        user_projects_path(current_user)
      end
    end
```

also refer this link: 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Answer (score 0):

Use devise `after_sign_in_path_for` method in aplication controller. For eg

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.role == "customer"
      redirect_to customer_dashboard_path
    elsif resource.role == "supplier"
     redirect_to supplier_dashboard_path
    end

  end
```

Comment: I tried this but still not having any joy. Seems to ignore it completely (Updated my question above for it)

Comment: U need to write this in application controller